# How to load js-yaml package?

Tags: reactjs

How do I load the [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-js) package in a ReactApp?

It looks like when I installed it via npm it was added to package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^31.0.2",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "yaml-js": "^0.2.3"
  },
```

but when I try to run `yaml.load` in my code I get the error

```
./src/App.js
  Line 56:  'yaml' is not defined  no-undef
```

Answer (score 4):

The following worked

`import yaml from 'yaml-js';`